# Unique page URL redirect to file_get_contents() at domain

Tags: pages, redirect, domain

I need to take a page from WordPess and 301 redirect itself to a sub-domain.

`Page` = http://adopttheweb.com/does-it-work/

`Domain` = http://wp-unique-page-url.adopttheweb.com/

*These are live, but they are not the intended project. I'm also using `if (is_page()){}` so it doesn't affect the entire site.*

`Domain` is actually `file_get_contents()` of `Page`, which is where this gets hairy...

---

The following is in the header of `Page` on the WP side.

**Javascript**

Obviously this would work perfectly but is off the table as it cannot 301.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://wp-unique-page-url.adopttheweb.com/";
</script>';
```

These are working solutions as far as 301 redirecting.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^adopttheweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^does-it-work/$ http://wp-unique-page-url.adopttheweb.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

**php**

```
function redirect_this($redirect_this){

        if( $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == 'adopttheweb.com/does-it-work/') {
            exit(header('Location: http://wp-unique-page-url.adopttheweb.com/', true, 301));
            //echo 'hello world';
        }
    }

    return redirect_this();
```

Getting to the page with a 301 isn't a problem except when `Page` gets to `Domain` it tries and tries to load and just fails. Headers are sent and no errors are shown.

---

The following is on the `Domain` side.

**php**

```
//
// Get contents of http://adopttheweb.com/does-it-work
//
$readfile = 'http://adopttheweb.com/does-it-work';

$pull = file_get_contents($readfile);
//
//
// Define stuff to be replaced
//
$find_replace = [ // Let's start our array
                    //
                    // Set our canonical URL
                    //
                    'http://adopttheweb.com/does-it-work/' => 'http://wp-unique-page-url.adopttheweb.com/',
                    //
                    //
                ];// Close the array
//
// This is where the magic happens
//
foreach ($find_replace as $key => $value){ // Now we take our array of each key and value
$pull = str_replace($key, $value, $pull); // Will look for matched keys and replace them with our new values 
}

echo $pull; // That's it
```

---

These are the headers at `Domain`.

**Header Reqeust**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: wp-unique-page-url.adopttheweb.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.481585522.1464331407; _gat=1
```

**Header Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 07:12:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 07:12:31 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

---

**What gives?**

I have no clue what's happening except that it's not working. I thought the `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == 'adopttheweb.com/does-it-work/'` being matched would do the trick as the headers clearly show the host as unique. I imagine it has to do with priority or something going on before the headers are sent and it's looping until it times out.

---

**Security?**

Someone pointed out this might be exploited. Is that the case? How?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Well after some more research and trying to reproduce the work I did that was failing, I managed to get it working...

Comment: Hey that's great! Feel free to add an answer here to help other users who come across the same problem :)

Comment: Ok I was wrong (after hours of trying to reproduce). I was hasty in my attempt and saw what I thought looked like it was working but was being called away from the computer... I will revise my question above with details.